# Pyramid subrequests

Tags: python, pyramid

I need to call GET, POST, PUT, etc. requests to another URI because of search, but I cannot find a way to do that internally with pyramid. Is there any way to do it at the moment?

Comment: Do you need to call views within your own application, or are you accessing another server altogether?

Comment: @MartijnPieters another server

Comment: Could you rephrase the question to e.g. “Sending requests from Pyramid application”?  “subrequests” is a term with a special meaning in Pyramid so this is misleading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use the existing python libraries for calling other webservers.

On python 2.x, use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), for python 3.x, use [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html) instead. Alternatively, you could install [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/).

Do note that calling external sites from your server while serving a request yourself could mean your visitors end up waiting for a 3rd-party web server that stopped responding. Make sure you set decent time outs.

Comment: to increase the user experience, you can make the request to the third party server via AJAX.

Answer (score 6):

pyramid uses webob which has a client api as of version 1.2

```
from webob import Request
r = Request.blank("http://google.com")
response = r.send()
```

generally anything you want to override for the request you would just pass in as a parameter.

```
from webob import Request
r = Request.blank("http://facebook.com",method="DELETE")
```

another handy feature is that you can see the request as the http that is passed over the wire

```
print r

DELETE  HTTP/1.0
Host: facebook.com:80
```

[docs](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#id1)

Comment: How would you use this for POST, PUT, etc requests?

Comment: Oh I see, I still feel like requests has a cleaner api, so I went ahead and use that, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Also check the response status code: response.status_int
I use it for example, to introspect my internal URIs and see whether or not a given relative URI is really served by the framework (example to generate breadcrumbs and make intermediate paths as links only if there are pages behind)